# Resolution always stuck at 640x480

Tags: drivers, display-resolution, amdgpu

In my Ubuntu 20.04.3 LTS the resolution always stuck at 640x480. I can change resolution with `xrandr` after login but as I start computer again it come back at 640x480. I don't want to use xrandr again and agian. Is there any different way to change resolution to 1024x768 permanently?

When booting I saw this error may be it is related to this issue :

[Problem1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/s2zqE.jpg)

[Problem2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JsOia.jpg)

GPU details :

```
06:00.0 VGA compatible controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] Picasso (rev c9) (prog-if 00 [VGA controller])
    Subsystem: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] Picasso
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 46
    Memory at e0000000 (64-bit, prefetchable) [size=256M]
    Memory at f0000000 (64-bit, prefetchable) [size=2M]
    I/O ports at e000 [size=256]
    Memory at fcc00000 (32-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=512K]
    Expansion ROM at 000c0000 [virtual] [disabled] [size=128K]
    Capabilities: <access denied>
    Kernel driver in use: amdgpu
    Kernel modules: amdgpu
```

Comment: There is "no EDID" error. Are you using some VGA adapter. You will need to replace it, or set resolution manually using `xrandr`. You can set the command to be run autimatically on boot.

Comment: Yes I'm using a VGA cable. Ok I'll try to set `xrandr` to run automatically.
Thanks You very much :)